# How to make particle effect in Andengine?

Tags: android, andengine, effects, particle-system

I'm developing a game by andengine.I need some particle effect for my game.
Game: There are balls in scene and they are moving by MoveModifier randomly.And when i touch them,they are getting lost.
I want: When they are getting lost,a particle effect occurs like glass broken, ball explosion or sth like that..
How can do that?

Answer (score 3):

you can view this [Project](https://github.com/pocmo/AndEngine-ParticleSystem-Demos) hope you will find some helpful resources

Answer (score 1):

Initialize particle emitter with center as (0,0).

```
IParticleEmitter emitter = new PointParticleEmitter(0,0);
```

Initialize particle system with your own parameters as follows.

```
ParticleSystem particleSystem = new ParticleSystem(emitter,5,10,50,textureRegion);
```

You may set blend function if you like.

```
particleSystem.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE);
```

Then you can add particleInitializers and ParticleModifiers according to your wish.

```
    particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new VelocityInitializer(-20, 20, -40, -60));
    particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new ColorInitializer(1f, 0.5f, 0.8f));
    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ExpireModifier(2f));
    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ColorModifier(1f, 0.88f, 1f, 0.6f, 0.8f, 0.3f, 0f, 0.4f));
```

Then you may attach this **particleSystem** object into your scene or any nodes.